# QGIS - How do you keep a map fixed to a template?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, maps

I am creating templates within print composer for people within my company to use. I would like them to include a map of the county in the top left corner that can then be used as an overview for whatever map they have created. How can I set it up so that they can just open the template with the map included without them having to open that map? When I add items from template and then save the whole thing as a template and open it later from a new project it opens up blank. The image I add in the top right corner also doesn't remain. I have locked them when I have saved them.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You would need to save an image of that map, then add it to the print composer as an image. Otherwise it's trying to use the map canvas of the current QGIS project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be providing the data as well as the layout.

Maybe you should create a template project, which includes the layout? That way you can ensure that your data sources used in the index map are loaded.

Either that or you should just use an image, as suggested above.

Comment: Thank you! I have made template projects and saved the print composer templates in each project.